# How to have pl/sql code skip over NULL values in multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am currently writing a PL/SQL script that is taking data from a cursor. The cursor is grouping by multiple grouping sets so I am returning  null values for multiple columns in a select few entries. Is there a way I can have my pl/sql script skip over these entries during my insert statement? I've tried using an IF statement but that doesn't work. Below is my code: Thanks in advance!

```
create or replace Procedure TEST_PROC IS
CURSOR c1 is
select sum(v.value_tx) as sum_of_values
     , max(c.create_dt) as max_calculation_dt
     , max(TRUNC(to_date((v.hr + ((v.utc_offset - 1)/24)), 'DD-MM-YY hh24:mi:ss'), 'iw')) as REPORT_PERIOD_DT
     , to_char((v.hr + ((v.utc_offset - 1)/24)),  'DD-MM-YY hh24:mi:ss') as CONVERTED_HR 
     , v.utc_offset
     , ff.form_field_label_tx
     , v.region_id 
     , v.hr_num
     , v.data_code
  from value v
  join calculation_value cv on v.value_id = cv.value_id
  join calculation c on cv.calculation_id = c.calculation_id
  join form_field ff on cv.form_field_id = ff.form_field_id

 where v.hr is not null
   and v.data_code is not null
   and v.utc_offset is not null
group by grouping sets(
(v.region_id, v.data_code, v.hr_num, v.utc_offset, ff.form_field_label_tx, ff.form_field_id, to_char(TRUNC(to_date((v.hr + ((v.utc_offset - 1)/24)), 'DD-MM-YY hh24:mi:ss'), 'iw'), 'dddyyyy'), TRUNC(to_date((v.hr + ((v.utc_offset - 1)/24)), 'DD-MM-YY hh24:mi:ss'), 'iw'), to_char((hr + ((utc_offset - 1)/24)),  'DD-MM-YY hh24:mi:ss'), ),
(v.region_id, v.data_code, v.hr_num, v.utc_offset, ff.form_field_label_tx, ff.form_field_id,  to_char(TRUNC(to_date((v.hr + ((v.utc_offset - 1)/24)), 'DD-MM-YY hh24:mi:ss'), 'iw'), 'dddyyyy'), TRUNC(to_date((v.hr + ((v.utc_offset - 1)/24)), 'DD-MM-YY hh24:mi:ss'), 'iw'), v.utc_offset), v.data_code
                   )
order by max(TRUNC(to_date((v.hr + ((v.utc_offset - 1)/24)), 'DD-MM-YY hh24:mi:ss'), 'iw')) desc;
l_var c1%ROWTYPE;
v_value_id value.value_id%type;
v_calculation_id calculation.calculation_id%type;
--
BEGIN
 Open c1;
        FETCH c1 into l_var;
                          insert into calculation (calculation_id,     calculation_date, calculation_name, report_period_dt)
                                               VALUES (null, sysdate, 'AGGWKL ' || l_var.REPORT_PERIOD_DT, l_var.report_period_dt)
                                               returning calculation_id into v_calculation_id;
 Close c1;
 Open c1;
    LOOP
        FETCH c1 into l_var;
        EXIT when c1%NOTFOUND;
  IF l_var.utc_offset is not null
  THEN
                          insert into value (value_id, energy_product_id, data_source_id, unit_cd, value_tx, utc_offset, data_date, hr_utc, hr, hr_num, data_code)
                                         VALUES (null, '777', '5', 'NA', l_var.sum_of_values, l_var.utc_offset, l_var.data_date, null, null, l_var.hr_num, l_var.data_code)
                                         returning value_id into v_value_id;
                          insert into calculation_value(calculation_value_id, calculation_id, value_id, form_field_id
                                      values (null, v_calculation_id, v_value_id, l_var.form_field_id);

           END LOOP;
           CLOSE c1;
END TEST_PROC;
```

Comment: Simplify your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @jarlh i simplified it a little bit , but i think it has something to do with the groupings that is messing something up so i thought that it would be helpful to have all the groupings in there to help replicate/display the issue. How would you recommend simplifying it?

Comment: What is not working, you get compilation_errrors?

Comment: Everything is compiling / running / inserting fine. I am just getting a LOT of entries being inserted. I'm guessing it is because of the groupings but I am getting entries such as (null, null, null, null) being inserted into my tables. Just was wondering how I can 'filter' these out

Comment: @John Wick - home work again? I hope so. First, why do you need PL/SQL to insert? Second, how about  IS NULL, IS NOT NULL - basics of Oracle SQL? SELECT... FROM... WHERE your value is NOT NULL, etc...

Comment: What would your recommended approach be?

Comment: Try watching this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BIswBoCnbpk

Comment: And create some simulated data similar to your data and post it.

Comment: how would i post it? just insert statements after create table statements?

Comment: @Art what is the best way to create 'simulated data' to post on here? an attachment? or a insert statement?

Comment: No idea. Make tables with similar data with nulls and not nulls, etc... It is not possible to tel why exactly your queries do not work just by looking at them. at least for me.

Comment: By the way, when would you recommend actually using PL/SQL over a bulk insert statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't point out in which table You get nulls so I'll try to answer only thing I see. It's a bit hard to write exact answer without some test data but as far I can see You have couple of problems:

```
insert into calculation (calculation_id,     calculation_date, calculation_name, report_period_dt)
     VALUES (null, sysdate, 'AGGWKL ' || l_var.REPORT_PERIOD_DT, _var.report_period_dt) returning calculation_id into v_calculation_id;
```

here You are inserting `null` into `calculation` table and then returning it into `v_calculation_id`

Similar thing is happening here:

```
insert into value (value_id, energy_product_id, data_source_id, unit_cd, 
                    value_tx, utc_offset, data_date, hr_utc, hr, hr_num, data_code)
VALUES (null, '777', '5', 'NA', l_var.sum_of_values, l_var.utc_offset, 
        l_var.data_date, null, null, l_var.hr_num, l_var.data_code)                                       returning value_id into v_value_id;
```

You are inserting `null` into `value` table and then returning it into `v_value_id`

and in the end You are inserting all those `nulls` into `calculation_value` here:

```
insert into calculation_value(calculation_value_id, calculation_id, value_id, form_field_id
values (null, v_calculation_id (this is null), v_value_id (this is null), l_var.form_field_id);
```

Comment: thanks! just to clarify, i am inserting a null because those IDs are automatically being generated by a trigger (sequence)